# Computational approach deciding whether a set of Wang Tile could tile the space up to some size

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry, tiling, mathematical-software

As an applied person, I'm facing one practical problem deciding whether a set of Wang tile could tile the plane periodically or aperiodically. Although both problems seem undecidable, but I'm on a more practical aspect. Say, if the program accidentally ("or systematically") find some "periodic structure", then it stops and tells me there exists periodic pattern. If during running, it enumerates all the use of tile and finds that it simply cannot tile the plane, then it tell me this set of tiles cannot tile the plane. Even if the program didn't stop, then after running some steps, it returns me a few most ordered patterns that that could "possibly tile the plane".

For practical purpose, I simply assume if the tessellation are up to some size (maybe 1000*1000) then I say "it could tile the plane practically".

So my most interested question is: is there any established programs or algorithms that "try" to help me analyze a set of tile even if it might not halt ("but I could define some imposed halting condition").

For context why I am interested in this problem, here's the links:

- [Coloring in lattice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147374/coloring-in-lattice)
- [Reference for Wang Tile](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149565/reference-for-wang-tile)
- [Periodic Tiling of Wang tile](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157214/periodic-tiling-of-wang-tile)

Also cross posted to [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157239/computational-approach-deciding-whether-a-set-of-wang-tile-could-tile-the-space).

Comment: all undecidable problems are equivalent. there is some scattered research into attacking undecidable problems. some of it is from the angle of proving program termination, some of it comes from automated theorem proving, some from the "busy beaver" problem, etc.... am working myself to tie some of this together.... it would help if you gave more bkg/motivation/detail on your particular problem... there seems not too much collective interest so far... see this [related question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19358/) asking for related refs

Comment: "all undecidable problems are equivalent." -- no, they are not; there's a hierarchy.

Comment: Please don't crosspost in this fashion; it's considered rude. Wait at least a few days so people have a chance to answer.

Comment: hah ok sigh my statement was a quick unqualified simplification fitting into a comment. _all undecidable problems at the same level of the undecidability hierarchy are equivalent_. the poster gives a "level 1" type problem aka Turing complete. anyway there is a general/widespread attitude in TCS that "once the problem is proven undecidable nothing more can be done" that this type of question is running against...

Comment: @vzn Thanks a lot for your reply, the actual problem is to understand the ground state of a physical crystal structure under pair interactions up to some ranges. It is likely that a physical crystal pattern is simply an order tiling of atomic ("cluster tiles") represented by Wang Tile... But the nature is usually well order (usually periodic), my goal is to review this pattern by computational force rather than ("imagination or manual construction of tiles")....

Comment: ok suggest maybe rephrasing the question in the physics formulation on [physics.se], it sounds like it would have been studied in that context & that should probably be used as the literature starting pt, can also [chat] on this further

Comment: @vzn Thanks for your comment. Indeed, this problem has been tackled partially in physics and some results has been obtained. However, the previous approach is done on a heavy manual manner (non-automizable) and I converted this problem into a tiling problem of Wang tiles. Once this tiling on a finite lattice problem is solved, all previous work can be reproduced and larger problem could be tackled automatically. That's why I resort to mathematics and computer science....

Comment: plz visit chat, the problem is too complex to analyze here. anyway any algorithm you can think of, even a simple one, is probably more than is known. are the tiles squares? if so a simple algorithm (to try) is to look for a large repeating supersquare. can detail this out. suggest working empirically & writing up an example with the least complex case/sample to analyze. know of some analysis of this problem via [a] post correspondence problem and [b] TMs but you would have to convert to those formats & it might only "blowup" and lead to large (unresolvable) instances.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on MathOverflow, which violates site rules.  If you'd like to answer this question, feel free to answer the copy over on MathOverflow.